# Using Grep in Java Code

Tags: java, string, text, grep

I have two identical arrays, Noun and Noun1, and want to find and extract the line that contains the combination of words (parliamenr reviews). I want to use grep command in linux and I wrote the following code:

```
        for(int i=0;i<noun.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<noun1.size();j++)
            {

                String id1 = noun.get(i);
                 String id2 = noun1.get(j);

                System.out.println(id1 +"\t"+id2);

                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "grep \"id1 id2\" /local//wiki-pmi/*.txt"};
                 Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
                 String line;
                 while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
                     System.out.println(line);
                 }


            }
        }
        fis.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is id1 and id2 do not refer to Arrays elements and the command search to find id1 and id2 in the text files instead. 
      String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "grep \"id1 id2\" /local//wiki-pmi/*.txt"};
Could Anyone help me to change the code in a way that id1 and id1 refer to the array (noun and Nooun1) elements?

Comment: You need to concatenate the string together: `"grep " + id1 + " " + id2 + ...

Comment: It is almost sure that this is not the right way to tackle the problem. Please explain what your two arrays contain and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JamesKingsbery you probably mean: `"grep \""+id1+" " + id2 +"\"...``

Comment: What does "parliamenr reviews" means ?

Comment: @alfasin Thanks for your response. "parliamenr reviews" are an example of the string query that I am going to find in the 6.6 GB text files. Do you know possibly what are options I have to handle such a giant files except HashMap and SQL which are nonfunctional? This way is very fast and efficient. If you know other way please let me know...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestion:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "grep \"" + id1 + " " + id2 + "\" /local//wiki-pmi/*.txt"};
System.out.println("First command: " + cmd[0]);
Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
```

Don't know if it really works, though, since I havn't got your context.

Comment: Thanks so much. It works now. However I don't understand why you wrote  "System.out.println("First command: " + cmd[0])"? it just print "First Command :/bin/sh"